# OracleParameter object is already contained in a collection

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

I am trying to execute oracle stored procedures from c# code.
i am trying to add oracle parameters to procedures. but I am getting exception like "OracleParameter object is already contained in a collection" while adding. please help me out this.

code:

```
using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Activity.Account
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SuccessLabel.Visible = false;
            FailureLabel.Visible = false;
        }

        protected void Create_user(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string oradb = "Data Source=OracleServerHost;User ID=scott;password=tiger";
            using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(oradb))
            {
                try
                {
                    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("create_users_372640", conn);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    OracleParameter p1 = new OracleParameter("u_user_id", UserIDTextBox.Text);
                    OracleParameter p2 = new OracleParameter("u_First", FirstNameTextBox.Text);
                    OracleParameter p3 = new OracleParameter("u_Last", LastNameTextBox.Text);
                    OracleParameter p4 = new OracleParameter("u_Email", EmailIDTextBox.Text);
                    OracleParameter p5 = new OracleParameter("u_password", PasswordTextBox.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(p1);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(p2);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(p3);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(p4);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(p5);
                    OracleCommand cmd_chk = new OracleCommand("check_user_372640", conn);
                    cmd_chk.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd_chk.Parameters.Add(p1);
                    conn.Open();
                    OracleDataReader rd = cmd_chk.ExecuteReader();
                    if (rd.HasRows)
                    {
                        rd.Read();
                        SuccessLabel.Visible = true;
                        FailureLabel.Visible = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        SuccessLabel.Visible = false;
                        FailureLabel.Visible = true;
                    }
                }catch(Exception){
                    Console.WriteLine("SQL Exception Occured");
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't have a parameter object in more than one collection.
Here is your problem :

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(p1);
cmd_chk.Parameters.Add(p1);
```

Comment: what is your recommendation?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, try to use Clone() function.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(p1.Clone());
```

It solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it worked for me:

```
command.Parameters.Add(p_me_id);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
command.Parameters.Clear();

command2.Parameters.Add(p_me_id);
command2.ExecuteNonQuery();
command2.Parameters.Clear();
```